# Disable bounce for sectionHeaderView only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sectionheader

I want to make following:
When I drag cells down so that make bounce effect, sectionHeaderView is dragging with first cell. And free space appears between sectionHeader and top edge of tableView. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kavzj.png)

But I want sectionHeaderView to stay separately from first cell. And free space should appear between sectionHeaderView and first cell when bouncing.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2EpU.png)

Is it possible?

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete, verifiable example to your question. What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could create your own "header" view that just sits above your table, not a part of your table. This should give you the behavior you're describing. Note that it will stay above the table view even while scrolling in the other direction.

Comment: _Why_ do you want this behavior?

Comment: That is customer's idea

Answer (score 0):

You could pin a fake header above the table view. That way it won't scroll with the table view.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it won't be replaced by the second and all other sectionHeaders in this case

Comment: No it won't. You should add that specification to your question.